# Stuck on Circles question on tangents

Tags: trigonometry, circles

[image]

Here the length of AO is equal to diameter of circle. AB and AC are tangents from A.

The triangle ABC has to be proved equilateral. I put it in geogebra and it was indeed equilateral. I can't find where to start the proof. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\triangle ABO \sim \triangle BMO,$$ since $\angle ABO=\angle BMO = 90^\circ$, and $\angle BOA = \angle MOB$.

Then

$$\dfrac{OB}{BM}=\dfrac{OA}{BA};$$
$$\dfrac{R}{BM}=\dfrac{2R}{BA};$$
$$2BM=BA;$$
$$BC=BA.$$
(where $R$ is the radius of the circle).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Its very helpful! But can I use pythagorus theorem for this proof?

Comment: Is it possible with pythagorus theorem?

Comment: No need for Pythagoras thm. OA is twice OB, in the right angled triangle OBC. Now use 30 degrees trig relation  OB/OA.

Comment: @Steve, yes, but it may be more long way. Denote $a=OM, b=BM, r=OB, c=AB$. Then $OA=2r$. By Pythagorean Theorem, $$b^2+a^2=r^2 \qquad (\triangle OMB),$$ $$c^2=(2r)^2-r^2=3r^2 \qquad (\triangle OBA),$$ $$b^2+(2r-a)^2=c^2\qquad(\triangle BMA),$$ $$b^2+4r^2-4ar+a^2=3r^2,$$ $$2r^2=4ar,$$ $$a=r/2,$$ $$b^2=\dfrac{3}{4}r^2=\left(\dfrac{c}{2}\right)^2,$$ $$b=c/2.$$ So long way :)

Answer (score 0):

Angle at tangent point $B$ is $90^0$

$$\sin BOA = \dfrac{BO}{AO} =\dfrac{1}{2}$$

$  BAO = 30^0 , BAC = 60^0,CBA = 90^0 - OBC = 60^0 $, so also for  BCA, making triangle ABC equilateral.

Comment: Is it possible with Pythagorus?